# Delete table lines based on not exist in another table and needs an additional "where"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble deleting some table lines based on a vehicle table and an order table. How can I do this smoothly when I know that in the vehicle table I only want to delete lines that has customer column = '14888'?

I'm trying something like this:

```
DELETE FROM VEHICLE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ORDER
    WHERE ORDERCUSTOMER=VEHICLE.CUSTOMER
)
AND VEHICLE.CUSTOMER = '14888'
```

This is giving me no lines, what am I doing wrong?

```
TABLE VEHICLE:
COL1: REG_NO     COL2:CUSTOMER     COL3:NOTE
AA001            14888             TEXT
AA002            15000             TEXT
AA003            14888             TEXT
AA004            14888             TEXT

TABLE ORDER:
COL1:ORDERNO      COL2:CUSTOMER    COL3:REGNO
001               15000            AA002 
002               14888            AA001
003               14888            AA003
```

What i want is to delete the VEHICLE line not in order and only for customer 14888. In this case i should only delete one line and that's the one with REGNO = AA004. I might perhaps have to include the REGNO here to get it to work?

Comment: What does `select count(*) from ORDER WHERE ORDERCUSTOMER = 14888` return?

Comment: Show us some sample data and specify the expected result. (Formatted text, please - not images.)

Comment: the select count gives 2 table lines

Answer (score 0):

Try the following by having that `and` condition within `exists`.

```
DELETE FROM VEHICLE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ORDER
    WHERE ORDER.CUSTOMER=VEHICLE.CUSTOMER
    AND ORDER.CUSTOMER = '14888'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DELETE FROM VEHICLE
WHERE VEHICLE.CUSTOME NO IN (
    SELECT ORDERCUSTOMER
    FROM ORDER
)
AND VEHICLE.CUSTOMER = '14888'
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.